# The dismiss button ("X") covers the text on the nomination prompt for recently suspended users

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, election, account-suspension

As the title says, the **X** button on the nomination prompt for recently suspended users covers the text. It looks something like this:

[image]

This happens in Safari 10.0.2.

Comment: Red circle is not free hand ... :(

Comment: @rene hence, [status-declined]

Comment: It should have been places over the full block of text :) instead of overlaying only a few letters